# What is Newton's theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, mathematical-physics

I'm reading a paper about mathematical physics at the moment and am wondering about the following:

> Let $w\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $w(x)=-\log|x|$ and $\mu\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be some non-negative integrable function radially symmetric about $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\int\mu(x)~dx=1$. Then by Newton's theorem $$(\mu\ast w)(x)\leq w(x)\text{ for a.e. }x.$$

What are they referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Here $\mu$ is the density of a planet in a two-dimensional universe.  $w*\mu$ is the gravitational potential caused by this mass.  Whereas $w$ is the gravitational attraction if all the mass of the planet were concentrated at the center of the planet.  It is known that if you are at a certain place in the universe, then the only part of the planet which has a non-zero net gravitational attraction upon you is precisely that part of the planet contained in a ball whose radius is your distance from the center of the planet.

For example, if the planet were a perfect hollow sphere (or in the 2D world, a perfect hollow circle), then anyone inside the sphere/circle would feel no gravitational attraction.  Whereas anyone outside the sphere/circle would feel the attraction as if the whole mass of the planet were concentrated at one point at the center.

Comment: Do you have some reference for a proof? Is the theorem correct as stated above it seems strange that it does not play a role about which point in space $\mu$ is radially symmetric. Shouldn't there somewhere be some $x_0$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a reference.  I didn't see the $x_0$, so maybe I made a mistake there.  I don't see how it can be true if $x_0 \ne 0$.  For example, suppose that $\mu(x) = \delta(x-x_0)$?